# Smtp emails not sending from my localhost but sending from my server

Tags: c#

I have a few websites that I use smtp client to send mails with. Up until today, all has been working fine but all of a sudden when I am debugging any site and I try send a mail, I get the timeout error. If I Publish my site and try send an email from it, it works fine ???

```
SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.ACCOUNT.co.za");

    // set smtp-client with basicAuthentication
    mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new
       System.Net.NetworkCredential("ACCOUNTNAME", "PASSWORD");
    mySmtpClient.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;

    // add from,to mailaddresses
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ACCOUNTEMAIL");
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress("EMAILADDRESS");
    MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);

    // add ReplyTo
    MailAddress replyto = new MailAddress("EMAILADDRESS");
    myMail.ReplyTo = replyto;

    // set subject and encoding
    myMail.Subject = "Password Request";
    myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    // set body-message and encoding
    myMail.Body = "MESSAGE";
    myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    // text or html
    myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
```

Yesterday it worked fine, I have not changed anything.

Comment: This is clearly a network issue and not a problem with your code.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are receiving? It does sound like a network error. Also, what is your question?

Comment: Thank you for you comment. That is what everyone says, but I cannot figure it out. My network is fine. Nothing has changed since yesterday :(

Comment: The error I get is :System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out. And my question is why is it all of a sudden not sending emails when I am debugging in my local host, but it sends the emails when the website is published on my server with the exact same code ?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a network issue, where you are not allowed to access the smtp server from your computer.

When debugging I usually disable network sending of smtp mails and instead redirect all outgoing mails to be saved as files in a temporary directory. That makes it a lot easier to debug and no risk that real users accidentally receive emails.

Add the following section to your development `web.config` - no code changes are required.

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="noreply@example.org">
      <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\temp" />
      <!-- The network host setting isn't used, but without it an exception
      occurs when disposing of the SmtpClient.-->
      <network host="localhost"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Sample taken from http://coding.abel.nu/2012/04/send-smtpclient-mails-to-disk/

Comment: Thank you. I will change my web.config file as a temporary solution until I can figure out what is causing this. It is very important for me to send these test mails, but for now I can use your solution

Comment: I did a telnet and it seems I am being redirected. I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

Ok if anybody else has this problem. Do a telnet and see if you can connect to your SMTP server. My problem was my network was changed without me knowing and it started blocking my emails.